# Deploying my website -- I'm totally stuck on what to do (django, gunicorn, nginx, gandi)

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I have been trying to figure out how to get my website online and I truly need some help. I'm sure this is a repost of something, but I have read everything I could find.

I wrote my website using django. It works. Let's call my website `myproject`.I am trying to link my website with the domain name I bought, which I will call `example.com`.

When I type `whois mysite.com` everything comes up, including three name servers: A.DNS.GANDI.NET, B.DNS.GANDI.NET C.DNS.GANDI.NET. I don't know what to do with those, if anything. I bought my domain name through Gandi.net.

I created a virtual environment on my raspberry pi, which I thought I would use as a host for now. This is probably a poor idea, but I don't fully understand the idea of hosting, especially because my website uses rabbitmq to connect to a database I have on my local network, so I know I need to connect to that somehow. My website does a large amount of computation, or rather it sends out a rabbitmq request to do a lot of computation on my home server and then processes the results on `myproject`.

On the virtual environment I created on my raspberry pi, I followed some guides and installed gunicorn and nginx. I can run gunicorn and access `myproject` through http://127.0.0.1:8001.

I CANNOT figure out how to get `myproject` onto `example.com`.

I 'bought' the free Simple Hosting website through Gandi, and I can "Edit my website" with a bunch of customization that I have already done in djago and html, so I don't want to do that.

This is my virtualenv/django setup:

gunicorn.config.py:

```
command = '/usr/local/virtualenvs/django_virtualenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/usr/local/virtualenvs/leagueofanalysis'
bind = '0.0.0.0:8001'
workers = 1
```

ngnix config file:

```
server {
server_name example.com;

access_log off;

location /static/ {
    alias /usr/local/virtualenvs/myproject/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
}
```

myproject django settings.py:

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*' # I need to change this, but what to???
...
```

Obviously I'm new to this, but I am a graduate student with a knack for computers and I've been using linux for 10 years so I am not new to programming or stuff like that. I just don't get this website jazz!

Please explain how I configure djano, gunicorn, nginx, and gandi.net to publish my website, and anything else you can tell that I am not understanding. If you also have suggestions about hosting, that would be appreciated since I know I cannot host on my raspberry pi but I do not understand how other services allow you host. For example, do you literally just ssh in, install gunicorn, nginx, rabbitmq, etc. and then copy your django project over and hit 'run'?

I have read a ton of guides and documentation over the last 10 days, but I am clearly missing something. If you post a link to a guide, please supplement it considerably with your own knowledge. Thanks!

Also, just let me know what other information you need if any.

Comment: Why is your nginx config proxy_pass to http://example.com:8001 if Gunicorn listen on 127.0.0.1:8001 ?
Or I would add listen 80; to nginx server block. I'm wondering if nginx is not automatically using port 80 when reaching example.com as the listen directive is not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

variable should contain a list of domains which you would like to serve your website on. For example if your variable looks like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".example.com", "foo.net"]
```

Your django application will serve your site on me.example.com example.com [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (notice the dot before "example") and foo.net but not on any other domains that are not within that list.

Also, your nginx and gunicorn setup seems a bit off. For this I'll point you [here](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). Follow this step by step, its a good tutorial on how to get gunicorn and nginx running using a socket file instead of a proxy_pass.